# sql replace value in 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I need to replace a number with some text in a query.

I use this code

```
SELECT [hostname]
  ,[assetTag]
  ,[business]
  ,[building]
  ,replace([Building],'700','ICT') AS BuildingNR
  ,replace([Building],'879','Sales') AS BuildingNR  
FROM [osdDB].[dbo].[all_machines]
```

This is the output

```
 hostname   assetTag    business    building    BuildingNR  BuildingNR
 ICT103961  A62609      ICT_IMO_E_M 879     879     Sales
 ICT107826  A72752      ICT_IMO_SALES   700     ICT     700
 ICT108923  A73433      ICT_IMO_SALES   700     ICT     700
 ICT113735  A86955A     ICT_IMO_IS  879     879     Sales
 ICT108071  A73642      ICT_IMO_SALES   706     706     706
 ICT110732  A86111      ICT_IMO_SALES   700     ICT     700
 ICT108929  A73427      ICT_IMO_SALES   700     ICT     700
 ICT109648  A72895A     ICT_IMO_MRN 700     ICT     700
 ICT110919  A86778      ICT_IMO_SALES   700     ICT     700
 ICT102048  B81606A     ICT_IMO_SALES   700     ICT     700
```

But I want this output

```
 hostname   assetTag    business    building
 ICT103961  A62609      ICT_IMO_E_M      Sales
 ICT107826  A72752      ICT_IMO_SALES    ICT
 ICT108923  A73433      ICT_IMO_SALES    ICT
 ICT113735  A86955A     ICT_IMO_IS       Sales
 ICT108071  A73642      ICT_IMO_SALES    ICT
 ICT110732  A86111      ICT_IMO_SALES    ICT
 ICT108929  A73427      ICT_IMO_SALES    ICT
 ICT109648  A72895A     ICT_IMO_MRN      ICT
 ICT110919  A86778      ICT_IMO_SALES    ICT
 ICT102048  B81606A     ICT_IMO_SALES    ICT
```

When I use it I get to much rows. I just want to fit it all in 1 row.

Comment: plz post the required output and complete query. and it would be better if u create a sqlfiddle

Comment: And the complete query

Comment: Number of rows returned depends on your `WHERE` clause. Post the rest of your query.

Comment: add a where clause to update the single row.

Comment: Having to columns with the same alias is not good™

Comment: Sorry; I placed my full query now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [case when](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statements instead of replacing values

```
SELECT [hostname],[assetTag],[business],[building],
    case [Building] 
            when 700 then 'ICT'
            when 879 then 'Sales'
            else 'Value if not 700 or 879'
    end as building
FROM [osdDB].[dbo].[all_machines]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was what I needed. I didn't think about the 'case when'.

Comment: i would prefer writing a function which would return a single value. And can be used in multiple select queries too.. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Using Function would be better:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[f_GetBuildingName]
(
    @Building int
)
RETURNS nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @value nvarchar(200)
SELECT 
    @value=case @Building
            when 700 then 'ICT'
            when 879 then 'Sales'
            else 'N/A'
    end
FROM [osdDB].[dbo].[all_machines]
RETURN @value
END
```

**Using Function in Select Query:**

```
SELECT [hostname],[assetTag],[business],[building],
    [dbo].[f_GetBuildingName](building) as building
FROM [osdDB].[dbo].[all_machines]
```

You can use this `function` in any `select` query and no need to write again `Case` statement again and again.

If you want to modify the result u have to modify the `function` only and not all the `select` queries where u use case statement for this operation.

Hope this helps you and others too..!:)